# VS2010: Error in Adding Reference of Project 1 into Project 2 and Vice Versa

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, class, mvvm

I am building a WPF application. I have two projects in my solution folder. One project is a WPF application which has a view, viewmodel and model class. 2nd project is a class library which has a view, vm and model class. I have added a reference of Project 2(class library) in project 1(wpf app) and I am able to access the contents of class.

But when I want to access the contents of class which belongs to Project 1(wpf app) in my project 2(class library) ViewModel, it throws me an error **"A type or namespace"xxxxx" could not be found"**

I want to access the member of all 3 classes(view,vm and model). Please help!!!!

Comment: If understand well the question, it seems to me that you want to make circular reference, which is not possible. One approach should be referencing from A to B direct, and reflection from B to A. But the is a smarter choice, extract all common classes into a shared assembly which is referenced by both projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well Lets say I added reference of B into A. How can i perform the reflection from A to B??

Comment: Check this link out http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/. But reflection is time consuming and slow, you should check the second approach, its more elegant.

Comment: Glad I could help. I converted comments into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand well the question, it seems to me that you want to make circular reference, which is not possible. One approach should be referencing from A to B direct, and reflection from B to A. But the is a smarter choice, extract all common classes into a shared assembly which is referenced by both projects.

Check this [link](http://csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples) out . But reflection is time consuming and slow, you should check the second approach, its more elegant.